# Limit number of items realized or detect items in view for LongListSelector

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I'm trying to implement infinite scrolling for the LongListSelector.

I initially populate the list with 15 items, and rely on the ItemRealized event to detect when I'm at the end of the list and need to load more. 5 items are visible on a WXGA screen at once.

My problem is that all 15 items are realized on the first load, and it immediately loads more. This is not desirable as each load is tied to an expensive network call.

Is it possible to limit the number of items to realize outside of view (I would set it to < 15), or is there a way to rely on items getting in view instead of being realized?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to maintain one property in your viewmodel which will decide when to load..
Code should be something like for any fixed item(here 15 in your case)

```
    private void ItemRealized(object sender, ItemRealizationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ItemKind == LongListSelectorItemKind.Item)
        {
            ViewModel vm = DataContext as ViewModel;
            var item = e.Container.Content;
            var items = nameoflonglistSelector.ItemsSource;
            var index = items.IndexOf(item);
            if (vm.Isloading == false && index == nameoflonglistSelector.ItemsSource.Count-1) //initally it will be false
            {
                vm.laodextraData();
                vm.Isloading = true;
            }
        }
    }
```